# How do I enter a formula in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm making a bot that erases certain columns and fills them in with new data. By erasing the data, the formula becomes

`=IFERROR(INDEX('AP query'!O:O,MATCH(Findings!#REF!,'AP query'!L:L,0)),"Non PO")`

So I tried making a macro and filling the cell with the formula but it says there's an error. Is there a fix or another way to enter the formula into the the cell using macros?

```
Range("B3").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('AP query'!O:O,MATCH(Findings!C3,'AP query'!L:L,0)),"Non PO")"
srcWorkbook.Worksheets("Findings").Range("B3").Copy
srcWorkbook.Worksheets("Findings").Range("B3:B" & LR).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
```

Answer (score 1):

When you wish to use a string in a formula `=IF(A1="Hi",...` in VBA, just "double up" the quotes:

```
Range("B3").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('AP query'!O:O,MATCH(Findings!C3,'AP query'!L:L,0)),""Non PO"")"
```

Because, as VBA compiles that line, it'll hit the first quote at `"Non Po"` and think that's the *end* of the line.  So (...trying to visualize it), it'd be reading that line like your formula is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('AP query'!O:O,MATCH(Findings!C3,'AP query'!L:L,0)),
```

Tangiental tip - sometimes when I hit similar issues, even just pasting the code here on SO, and formatting it as code, helps because as you can see in your post, the `Non PO` is a different color, but all formulas (strings maybe?) should be the same (all red, as in the answer I posted above).

Comment: Thanks, it works!